# How to get sass and font modules working for a single feature of an Angular/Webpack application?

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, jhipster

I'm having sass problems in my JHipster project. I'm not sure whether what I want to do isn't doable or if I'm just doing something wrong. Specific or general advice, or examples would be much appreciated.

I am trying to add [this dashboard demo](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin) as a feature to [my app](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-example-application/blob/dashboard/src/main/webapp/app/features/dashboard/dashboard.page.scss). It uses several scss, css and font files which are declared globally in the [`.angular-cli.json`](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin/blob/master/.angular-cli.json#L22-L33) file of the demo. I would like these styles to apply to components within this feature only and not the entire application. If possible, I would like these styles and fonts to load lazily along with the features's javascript code that [does load lazily](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-example-application/blob/dashboard/src/main/webapp/app/features/features.routing.ts#L18).

My understanding of both sass and style modules is very basic. There's probably something wrong with my [`webpack.common.js`](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-example-application/blob/dashboard/webpack/webpack.common.js) too.

With things as they are, I get many errors that look something like this:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/app/features/dashboard/dashboard.page.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/ionicons.woff?v=2.0.1' in '/Users/Dan/work/gba/src/main/webapp/app/features/dashboard'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/app/features/dashboard/dashboard.page.scss 6:67172-67213
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/features/dashboard/dashboard.page.scss
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/features/dashboard/dashboard.page.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/features/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/features/features.routing.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/features/features.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9070 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main
```

Comment: You might not have a loader for `woff`? You probably want `file-loader` to handle font files.

Comment: oh yeah, just looked, you have `woff2` but not `woff`:

`{
                    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/i,
                    loaders: ['file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]']
                },`

Comment: I think that the '?' means that the preceding character is optional. That way jpe?g matches both jpg and jpeg and woff2? matches woff and woff2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to get a few things just right or it won't work and to do that you have to understand everything. The breakthrough came when I changed my webpack rule to output modules (files) with their original names instead of the hashed ones.

```
// webpack.vendor.js
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/i,

            // originally
            use: ['file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=content/[hash].[ext]']

            // preserving the file names.
            // use: ['file-loader?name=content/[name].[ext]']
```

That showed me which files were actually being copied to target. The font-awesome ones were working. Then I saw that a `$fa-font-path` variable was being set in my `vendor.scss` file and I looked into the effect of that. My code didn't refer to this variable, but there was a reference to it inside a font-awesome file in node_modules/. In that file this variable was given a default (bad) value that was overridden by the (good) value in my `vendor.scss` file. Some of the other vendor libraries also had variables like this that also received bad default values that were not overridden. Once I added lines to `vendor.scss` to override these defaults it started working.

```
// vendor.scss
$fa-font-path: '~font-awesome/fonts';
$roboto-font-path: '~roboto-fontface/fonts';
$ionicons-font-path: "~ionicons/fonts";
```

On top of that, I had build instructions for third party libraries in both `webpack.common.js` and `webpack.vendor.js`. I don't know if that matters.